# How to play streaming audio using mms protocol

Tags: android, streaming, record, mms

I want to record audio from webserver using mms protocol on android phone.
present, I'm record streaming audio.
But, I can't seek while play recorded audio.
If you know record and play streaming audio using mms protocol, please let me know.
Important, while play recorded audio, user can seek with seekbar.

Answer (score 0):

```
    URL url = new URL("http://myradio,com/stream.mp3");
    inputStream = url.openStream();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "url.openStream()");

    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputSource);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FileOutputStream: " + outputSource);

    int c;

    while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "bytesRead=" + bytesRead);
        fileOutputStream.write(c);
        bytesRead++;
    }
```

or go to [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html)